# How do I view the string pulled from feeds image importer?

Tags: media, feeds, debugging

I am importing images from a feed using xPath parser. I think that I have the correct attribute value, `media:content@url`, but I am getting a `Unable to handle the provided embed string or URL.` error. My first instinct is to check that I'm getting the proper string. How do I do this? Is there a way through devel to view the imported string? Devel?

The url string I want to pull is `https://cdn2.orgsync.com/images/os-photos/s5o0zqk8o29mi46_710.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved my problem, but I found the hook needed to spit out the pre-parse data.

```
\**
* Importer testing.
*/
function wpi_events_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
dpm($result);
}
```

This spits out the source strings, which is great, because it tells me my xpath selector is wrong.